# Combine two strings to DateTime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have two variables. One variable represents a date from a datepicker on windows phone and the other variable represents a time from a timepicker. Now I want to combine these two strings to one string to represent the whole value.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) their concatenation to create your time:

```
var myTime = DateTime.Parse(DateValue + " " + TimeValue);
```

or if you have your datetimepicker and timepicker:

```
var myTime = datetimepicker.Value.Date
                    .AddMilliseconds(timepicker.Value.TotalMiliseconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you just want to combine the strings:**

```
 string combination = datetimepicker.ToString() + " " + timepicker.ToString();
```

more: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-append

```
datetimepicker.Hour = timepicker.Hour ;

datetimepicker.Second= timepicker.Second;


...
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer. But I need a DateTime out of the two strings. But if I try Convert.ToDateTime(datetimepicker.ToString() + " " + timepicker.ToString()) have not that function. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasSebastianJensen perhabs the added part will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
date.ToString() + " " + time.ToString();
```